# Distributing key shares

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, key

I have the following Problem: A master key is distributed with N key shards. In order to restore the master key, a threshold number T of keys must be provided, where N > T > 0. Additionally we a have a number of receivers for the key shards. There is a side condition, that states, that at least 2/3 of all key holders shall be able to reconstruct the master key. What (combinatoric) algorithm do I need to calculate the distribution of key shares to the holders?

Comment: stackoverflow is not here to solve your "homework", without you doing anything. So provide what you tried, your ideas, etc.

Comment: True. All I'm asking for is a direction :)

Answer (score 0):

The search query that you are looking for is *[Secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing)*. The traditional example of this is [Shamir's scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing). There's a lot of resources on the internet which explain quite well how these schemes work in detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not quite what I asked for. The main question is how to distribute the key shards resulting from shamir's secret sharing algorithm among all receivers, so that the condition is met.

Comment: I think I don't really understand what you mean. Shamir secret sharing, with 3 participants and threshold value 2 gives you 3 key shares. You would give each of them a key share. 2 of them can use their key shares to restore the secret (because the threshold is 2).